# Conky 1.11.6 - Want to eliminate gaps above/below graphs

Tags: linux, monitoring, conky

### Environment

- Debian Linux 11.5 "bullseye"
- Conky 1.11.6 (compiled 2020-08-17, package 1.11.6-2)
- Xorg 1.20.11 (package 2:1.20.11-1+deb11u2)
- FVWM version 3 release 1.0.5 (built from git 23854ad7)

### Problem

I am trying to reduce the Conky window to show just a single graph (chart, plot) with absolutely no other elements.  However, it seems Conky keeps adding a gap/border/margin/padding/spacing, above and below the plot area.  The gaps appear as horizontal bars in the background color.  I've tried every Conky option I can find, but the gap won't go away.

### Investigation

I've got gaps, margins, and border width set to zero.  I've disabled all borders, ranges, scales, outlines, and shades.  I've got the window and graph both set to 64 by 64.  If I reduce the graph height, the entire window gets shorter, but the gaps remain in proportion.  Likewise for increasing the graph height.  If I resize the Conky window smaller with window manager controls, it clips off the graph.  I can crop the bottom border this way, but not the top.

### Screenshot

In the combined screenshots below, the magenta arrows point to the gaps.  The bright green is the plot area.  The dark gray surrounds are window manager decorations, and serve to show where the black Conky window background ends.  These are both `${cpugraph}` charts, with the CPU made artificially busy for test purposes.

[image: combined screen capture of two Conky windows]

### Config

The Conky config that produced the above is:

```
conky.config = {
    own_window = true,
    own_window_type = 'normal',
    own_window_transparent = false,
    own_window_hints = '',
    alignment = 'top_middle',
    own_window_title = 'conky_gaptest',
    double_buffer = true,
    disable_auto_reload = true,
    top_cpu_separate = false,
    update_interval = 0.5,
    show_graph_range = false,
    show_graph_scale = false,
    draw_outline = false,
    draw_shades = false,
    draw_borders = false,
    draw_graph_borders = false,
    gap_x = 0,
    gap_y = 0,
    border_inner_margin = 0,
    border_outer_margin = 0,
    border_width = 0,
    extra_newline = false,
    default_color = 'white',
    maximum_width = 64,
    default_graph_width = 64,
    default_graph_height = 64,
    }
conky.text = [[${cpugraph cpu0 64,64 00ff00 00ff00}]]
```

Anyone have any suggestions?

### Background

(I am doing this because I want to make the Conky window suitable for swallowing into FvwmButtons.  I have a vaguely NeXTstep-esque dock/wharf/panel/sidebar, made of 64x64 pixel buttons.  I'd like some of the buttons to be Conky graphs.  But as long as those gaps are there, it wastes part of the tiny 64x64 space.  `wmload` doesn't have this problem, but sucks in other ways.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conky object `voffset` changes the vertical offset position of the object following it by a given positive or negative number of pixels. A construction like the following *may* do what you need, where a negative value determined by trial-and-error should be substituted for each of y1 and y2:

```
conky.text = [[${voffset y1}${cpugraph cpu0 64,64 00ff00 00ff00}${voffset y2}]]
```

In determining y1 and y2, I'd recommend first using the following construction and determining y1 alone by trial-and-error:

```
conky.text = [[${voffset y1}${cpugraph cpu0 64,64 00ff00 00ff00}]]
```

Then, add in the second `voffset` term and determine y2 by trial-and-error.

Comment: A quick test showed y1 of -4, y2 of -10 give a good appearance for me.

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you both!